# How to deploy/connect a React/Flask-RESTful app?

Tags: reactjs, flask, server, web-hosting, flask-restful

I am relatively new to web development so if what I am trying to do here is not a common practice in the community, please de not hesitate to correct me.

I have written a simple **react** app that communicates with a **Flask-rest** API at the back-end via HTTP requests. For test use, I am running the React app and the Flask api separately on different ports on localhost and connect them using a proxy configuration, so the url for the HTTP request could remain **relative** (e.g. `/getUser/user_id` etc)

My question is, how would I deploy the APP and the API onto the same server so the structure would not change? Or do I need two different servers to host each of them? I might as well admit that really don't understand how a server actually works... If I run `yarn build` for the React app, should I put the the build folder together with the Flask API?

A related question is that, I have saved several static files on the back-end and I would like my front-end React app to have access to them and so far I have tried Flask's `send_from_directory()` function to make it work. Is this the right/common way to serve a static file on the server? I have seen people mentioned **Nginx** but I don't quite understand that..

Any answers or comments are appreciated. Thanks for helping a new programmer out

Answer (score 2):

My recommendation would be to deploy with [Heroku](https://www.heroku.com/). You will only need one server (for Flask) and can compile your React code to be served with your Flask application.

This repository should help: https://github.com/chosak/heroku-python-react